# get string with new line character inside

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I need to construct a string (character) with a new line character which needs to passed onto another function - example below.

```
> a <- 5
> b <- 3
> paste("A is:", a , "\n", "B is:", b)
[1] "A is: 5 \n B is: 3"
```

My actual use case is as below.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("A", "B", "C", 'D'), b=seq(1:4))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=a,text=paste("a is:", a, "\n", "b is:", b) )) + geom_bar(aes(y=b), stat='identity')
ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
```

this gives below chart, however I need the new line character in the `tooltip` so that `a is :B` and `b is:2` appears on two lines

[image]

Comment: use `<br />` instead of `\n`?

Comment: tried `<br />` ,  doesn't put the text into two lines

Comment: I tried it, it did work

Comment: `library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(a=c("A", "B", "C", 'D'), b=seq(1:4))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=a,text=paste("a is:", a, "<br>", "b is:", b) )) + geom_bar(aes(y=b), stat='identity')
ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqPbr.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139691/discussion-between-maximilian-peters-and-rawr).